# Erro ao gerar relatorio, somente no servidor

Tags: java, servidor, ireport, glassfish

Possuo uma aplicação no NetBeans, decidi colocar ela no ar, fiz um servidor aws na Amazon, configurei meu *glassfish* no servidor, e subi a aplicação, a configuração do *glassfish* é a mesma da minha maquina local. O problema, é que quando eu gero o relatório local (na minha maquina, não pelo endereço do servidor) eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:777)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:224)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextImpl.java:851)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1208)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:405)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Porem, comecei a pesquisar aqui, o meu arquivo `.war` no servidor só tem isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Parece que minhas classes não vieram juntas, sera que o erro é devido a isso? Localmente no NetBeans ele gera normal.

Comment: Essa pergunta é identica a outra. Se a intenção era adicionar o print, era só ir na outra, editar e adicionar nela. Sugiro também que leia [ask] para entender como elaborar uma boa pergunta.

Comment: poise, me desculpa, me perdi aqui

Comment: vc consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Sugiro que apague esta pergunta(vai ser fechada como duplicata de qualquer jeito), adicione o print na outra pergunta e edite ela com mais detalhes de como e quando o problema ocorre. Do jeito que tá, eu pelo menos não faço a minima ideia do motivo do erro. Adicione o código também que está disparando o erro.